# What does this batch file code execute?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I understand Call runs the batch file

I'm confused because:

- I couldn't find make as a batch command
- Update Serial is a function within the makefilep so is anything spaced after the file search calling a function within that file?
- Where are -f and other similar command definitions defined? I can find all the batch file commands on various websites but I'm not quite sure on a keyword to find all of these listed on a website or if there is a specific name for these.

Code  is as follows:

```
ECHO ---------------------------------------------
CALL make -f Makefilep
CALL make -f Makefilep UpdateSerial
```

Comment: I bet this is not about DOS ...

Comment: If you're not sure what program or batch file `call make` is running, try `where make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor correction to your understanding of `CALL`: `CALL` executes a batch file (or subroutine in the current batch file) *and returns to the calling batch file*.

What is happening in this batch file is that `make` is being executed, with the *parameters* (*not* commands) `-f` and `Makefilep` being passed to the first time it is called, and the parameters `-f`, `Makefilep`, and `UpdateSerial` being passed the second time.

What those parameters mean is defined by the `make` program; if `make` is a batch file, you would have to look at its code to determine what they mean. If they are executable files (.exe), you will have to consult any provided documentation.

While `CALL` is primarily used for calling batch files and batch subroutines, it can also be used with executables (.exe). However, it's not *needed* with executables; normally, when an executable finishes its run, the batch file resumes from where it left off.

Comment: Another use of call is to force delayed expansion on argument variables with doubled percent signs when using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!var!` is not possible or in addition to that (index variable set in a code block for example).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the context is, but it could be related to [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments